# Get distribution for aggregate loss using Monte Carlo

Tags: risk, risk-management, monte-carlo, risk-models, simulations

I am given two data sets containing dates and losses (in some currency).

Given a distribution for the amount of losses and an (a,b,0) distribution for frequency of losses, how can I use Monte Carlo simulations to get a distribution for aggregate losses?

The papers and books I see online seem to state how to simulate aggregate losses (by simulating # of losses and losses given such #), but how do I come up with a distribution given all that data?

There's this book I found "Operational Risk with Excel and VBA". It  describes the procedure and ends with the mean, standard deviation and other moment stuff. Is that sufficient to describe the distribution of aggregate losses?

[image]

Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136541/get-distribution-for-aggregate-loss-using-monte-carlo

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, what do you want to know: 1. Do you want to know how to do a Monte-Carlo simulation given a frequency and severity distribution? 2. Do you want to know how to calibrate a specific parametric distribution to your data at hand? Or do you want to know how to choose such a parametric distribution in the first place?

Comment: And by the way, given that losses from operational risk often are very heavy tailed, I would consider carefully whether a distribution for such losses should have finite variance

Comment: @gg I want to know how to fit a distribution of aggregate losses after simulating them. What's weird is that the book doesn't mention how to after simply stating the moments

Comment: I am still not sure I understand because what you seem to want sounds somewhat unusual. Normally people fit frequency and severity and then simulate exactly to avoid doing a fit to the aggregate distribution. Why do you need a parametric representation of the aggregate losses, if you can simulate them?

Comment: @gg I have no idea with my professor. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- For each $i$ in $1$ to number of Mont-Carlo runs $K$
- simulate the number of losses $N_i$
- simulate $N_i$ many loss-sizes $X_{i,1},\ldots,X_{i,N_i}$
- calculate $L_i = \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} X_{i,j}$

Doing this you get a sample of losses $L_1,\ldots,L_K$ and you can do all sorts of hisograms, density fits, VaR, ES calculations on it.

EDIT: on this sample you could try to fit a loss distribution (e.g. Gamma or translated Gamma see [here](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlnode116.html)) by maximum likelihood or method of moments. But you can apply the method of moments even without MC becauase if you assume that the number of losses and the loss sizes are independent then
$$
E[L] = E[N]E[X] \text{ and }
V[L] = E[N]V[X] +E[X]^2 V[N]
$$
for these fromulas and fitting distributions see e.g. [again here](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlnode116.html).

Comment: "density fits" How? That is precisely what I want to know how to do given all those Li's

Comment: See the EDIT and the link for the moment and the Gamma distribution.

Comment: THANK YOU, @Richard...I think. I'll check it out and see it if helps.

Comment: Is anything but translated gamma and the parameters relevant? Btw how do I calculate E(L^3)? Do I cube each L then get average? There doesn't seem to be a formula in the article for E(S^3). There's E(S) and Var(S) but nothing that gives me something for E(S)...btw how do I calculate E(S) and E(S^2)? Do I get them from N and X or do I sum up from simulated S's?

Comment: Yes you can average $L^3$ from the sample or you look [here](http://www.casact.org/pubs/forum/11spforum/Halliwell.pdf) on page 8 for the formla of the skewness in the collective risk model. If you like my answer then don't forger to accept ;)

Comment: Sorry dumb question actually. Of course it's supposed to be average. Otherwise , we wouldn't simulate in the first place. Btw, every set of simulations seems to give me quite vastly different parameters. X_0 in particular. Do you know what to do about this? Do I simulate 1000 X_0 values and then get average? It seems to long since even if 100 values since each set of simulations is supposed to be 2000...if worst comes to worst maybe I should just fit a translated gamma in R by some code...

Comment: You try to fit this $x_0$ by the method of moments (as I have seen in the other question). Maybe this estimte has too much variance. Try maximum-likeliohood instead. It should work too.

Comment: Too much variance --> I think that describes it PERFECTLY. Hopefully I find some R code to fit a translated gamma. Otherwise, I guess I will just estimate with averaging (method of moments, was it?)